# How to define 'filter' on WCT?

Tags: polymer-2.x, web-component-tester, wct

[image] how to read property 'filter' on WCT
       I'm getting error when I run WCT "Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"
       How can we define a filter on WCT suites

Comment: This error means that `this.obj` is `undefined`. It look like you're expecting `this.obj` to be an Array instead, but either 1. The code that's supposed to set it to an array hasn't run yet, or 2. `this` isn't the object you think it is and doesn't have an `obj` property. Without seeing the rest of your code we can't diagnose this further. The first step toward debugging it would be to find out what the actual value of `this` and `this.obj` are with e.g. `console.log(this)`.

Comment: Hi Jordan,this.obj getting above json.I just updated my code.That is getting correct value